# Print out different item from Arraylist one after another

Tags: java, arraylist

I will try to explain my problem. I have an Arraylist with several strings. I have an output method:

```
    ArrayList<String> testList = new ArrayList<String>();
    testList.add("test1");
    testList.add("test2");
    testList.add("test3");
    testList.add("test4");
    public static void output(int testIndex) {

        for (int i = 0; i < testList.size(); i++) {
        }
 System.out.println("Domain: "+ testList.get(testIndex));


    }
```

So depending on what data I need, I can use my output method and enter my values. If I enter 0 as testIndex, it will print out "test1".

I want to make this a little better though. What I want to do is whenever I call my output method, I want it to print out the first item. When I call it again the second time, I want it to print out the second item. When I call it a third time, I want to print out the third item.. and so on.

How do I do this? Can Java do this? I also don't want to remove anything from my Arraylist.

Comment: so whats the problem just pass different index each time or make `testIndex` as global and increase it everytime?

Comment: What's the reason for the `for` loop that does nothing in it's the body?

Comment: @ChetanKinger I removed some code that was not necessary for my question.

Answer (score 2):

You could save the current position in a data member:

```
private static testIndex = 0;
public static void output() {
    System.out.println("Domain: "+ chunkList.get(testIndex));
    ++testIndex;
}
```

Comment: you should be careful not to call the method `5` or more time then list size

Comment: `counter` does not necessarily have to be `static` depending on the behavior expected by the OP.

Comment: @ChetanKinger since `output` is defined as `static` (in the OP), `testIndex` also has to be, so the method could access it. Of course, you could them both of them as non-`static`, but I'm not sure if that would be the correct semantic for the OP's situation.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to have a int value that is the counter that will increment each time you call the output method such as:

```
int counter = 0;
```

and if you call your output method you then post increment it:

```
output(counter++);
```

Make sure you check if the counter is equal or greater than the size of your arraylist.

Comment: `counter` wouild have to be `static` depending on the behavior expected by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use queue instead of arraylist.
Syntax is :

```
Queue queue = new LinkedList(); 
queue.element()
```

To get the output without deleting it from the list

Comment: That is not necessary. Rod_Algoquin and Mureinks solutions worked perfectly fine. Thank you anyway Kushagra.

Comment: Welcome Sandeep but I would suggest use the correct data structure as per the requirement instead of using other DS and modifying them